# Counting Distinct numbers using collections

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to count distinct numbers using collection. Part of code is as below:

```
With ActiveSheet
ArrCSID = .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Value2
Columns("A").Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

On Error Resume Next
For Each a In ArrCSID
    CollecUniqueCSID.Add a, a
Next

For d = LBound(ArrCSID, 1) To UBound(ArrCSID, 1)
    <<Some validation check on the values of ArrCSID>>
Next d

CountCSIDTotal = d - 1
CountCSIDDistinct = CollecUniqueCSID.Count
```

This is not working. The CountCSIDDistinct value is 0 for input (1,1,2,2) whereas the expected value is 2.  Could someone help me with a fix? Have to use collection, cannot use dictionary or any other data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem appears to be with how you add the item to the collection.  If you comment out the `On Error Resume Next` line you'll start to see the errors.

Collection Add method definition looks like this:
[image]

By this: `CollecUniqueCSID.Add a, a` your saying `a` is the value and the key.  The problem is that the key needs to be a string and your entering an integer.

If this is what you really want then cast the integer to a string like this:

```
CollecUniqueCSID.Add Item:=a, Key:=CStr(a)
```

This of course will throw an error if you have a duplicate key which might be why you have the `On Error Resume Next` line in order to skip duplicates.

---

If you are looking for storing both values like a xy point, use an array instead:

```
CollecUniqueCSID.Add Item:=Array(a, a)
```

Comment: Changing the add statement as follows worked: 

CollecUniqueCSID.Add Item:=a, Key:=CStr(a)

Thank you so much @Portland Runner